# Why are features added to layers via Python script not being displayed?

Tags: pyqgis, features, import, vector-layer, copy

I am using PyQGIS with QGIS version 2.18.11.

Can layer.addFeature() be used on a layer which is a clone of a layer which was imported from a .xml file?

This code throws no errors:

```
def updateDestination(self, importLayer, masterName):
    masterLayer = Utils.getLayerByName(masterName)
    self.iface.setActiveLayer(masterLayer)
    self.iface.actionDuplicateLayer().trigger()

    tempLayer = Utils.getLayerByName(masterName + " copy")
    tempLayer.startEditing()
    tempLayer.setLayerName(masterName + "_temp")

    for feature in importLayer.getFeatures():
        print "Adding feature", feature["ID"]
        tempLayer.addFeature(feature)

    tempLayer.commitChanges()
    tempLayer.updateFields()
    tempLayer.updateExtents()
```

But, when I go to check the attributes table, it still only has the original data. If the action sequence I require is

1. Clone layer
2. Add features to the end of that layer
3. UI button to trigger continuing
4. Delete clone layer
5. Add features to the end of the original layer

Am I limited to using something that isn't an imported vector file? Data was originally entered into an Access Database. xlm was used to transfer some test data across.